# include() working on localhost but not on live website

Tags: php, wordpress, mpdf, contact-form-7

I have a situation where a php line is working in localhost, but not on live website. The line of code is below:

```
include( get_template_directory().'/mpdf-master/mpdf.php');
```

I am using

- WordPress 4.6.1
- Contact form 7 Plugin - version 4.5
- mPDF library to create PDF
- Php version in localhost:- 5.6 and in live webserver:- 5.5

What would be the reason behind such behavior?

**EDIT:** On inspecting i found an ajax error

```
JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Does this helps to resolve issue?

Does this happens due to directory permission 755?

Comment: Probably wrong path. Check the error you get.

Comment: You can echo the get_template_directory() to see what does it contain.

Comment: Same path used in localhost, its working perfect. Same directory structure in live website as in localhost

Comment: where did you add this in functions.php or in any other template?

Comment: I am using it in fuctions.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/mpdf-master/mpdf.php');` instead.

if you are trying to call the file in functions.php use the below one than.

```
require_once( TEMPLATEPATH."/mpdf-master/mpdf.php" );
```

if there is a wrong path it must tell you in the browser or just enable the debug to understand whats wrong

If still not working the problem can be a js conflict between contact form 7 and mpdf

Comment: Thanks for your time. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. On inspecting i found an ajax error coming "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data"

Comment: Than your problem can be a conflict with contact form 7 try to disable contact form 7 and see if it works

Comment: am using this with contact form 7 hook 'wpcf7_before_send_mail'

Answer (score 0):

try like

```
include( dirname(__FILE__).'/mpdf-master/mpdf.php');
```